# jQuery Mobile input widths

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to change the width of the `<input>` tags on my jQuery Mobile page, any ideas?

http://www.nuhack.com/stackoverflow-question/

Comment: override `div.ui-input-text` and `div.ui-input-search` for search input http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bRszY/ as `type=search` is different than other input types.

Comment: Pop that in an answer and I'll accept it @Omar - perfect, I've been messing with that for ages!!! [THANKS!]

Comment: you can also override `.ui-btn` but this will override all buttons with that class. Alternatively, use `<a>` with `data-role=button` and give it a custom class then override it` i.e. `.ui-custom-btn { width: 50px !important }` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bRszY/ Demo is updated with a custom button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery Mobile wraps all input types in a div with class `.ui-input-text` except for `type=search` which has class `.ui-input-search`. All you need is to override those classes.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bRszY/)**

All input types:

```
div.ui-input-text { width: 50px !important }
```

input type search:

```
div.ui-input-search { width: 50px !important }
```

Comment: @Omar: Hi omar, I think submit buttons class is `ui-input-btn` and not `ui-input-text`. Setting the same width for `ui-input-text` and `ui-input-btn` doesn't reflect the same width on UI actually. Weird

Comment: @Malloc Hi, I will check this. Maybe 1.4 is different if you're using it. are you using `input` or `button` tags?

Comment: I used input tag when I wrote my comment above. But now I am using button tags and the issues of width are fixed :)

Comment: How to change the size for just one JQM input? CSS selectors are not working for me.

Comment: @Vito this should be done by js. Or wrap that input with a div, give that div a class or an id, then override it by CSS. E.g. `.foo .ui-input-text { new styles }`.

Answer (score 4):

to make the button wrapped  around the text, use data-inline="true"

```
<input  data-inline="true" id="btn_1"  type="button" value="click here"/></h4>
```

Comment: accepted answer doesn't work for me, this does. Thanks